# Create air intake from submerged water pump…?

Tags: filters

I'm setting up a wet / dry aquarium filter and I'd like to handle both the water return and the protein skimming (foam generation) with only 1 submerged power head, a situation consisting of 1 submerged pump for 2 purposes: 75% water return to the main fish tank above and 25% air suction created with the water for an air stone that generates foam for the protein skimmer.

The power head label indicates that it has a max pump amount of about 237 GPH (I'm betting it's closer to maybe 200 GPH). The current outlet from the unit that connects to the 5/8" return tube is a 1/4" nozzle. My thoughts are to mod the pump (or more likely, the hose) to allow just enough air suction to feed the air stone. I'm hoping there's a way to somehow use a tee connector from the main return that could somehow use gravity to suck air into a separate branch and push just enough air into the air stone (for a custom protein skimmer fitting). Have any of you done something similar to this?

What I'm unsure about is whether a mod like this would suck enough air into the tube (assuming it's even possible). I did stumble onto a blog where someone apparently modded the impeller chamber to suck in air and I think they were able to push enough air into a separate chamber that caused enough foam generation.

The idea here is to create just enough water vacuum necessary to suck air into a separate line that would then feed the air stone with air while simultaneously pushing water back into the above main tank with the primary branch of the 5/8" tube (all from a single submerged pump, thereby eliminating the need to buy another pump).

Any insight into this would be appreciated.